# Taylor Expansion with matrices

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion

The following formula should be expanded with the Taylor Expansion in $\lambda$:
$$(A-\lambda B)^{-1}$$
In a first  step this can be re-written as
$$(\mathbf 1-\lambda A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}$$
The taylor expansion is then supposed to be
$$\left(\mathbf 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\lambda A^{-1}B)^n\right)A^{-1}$$
However, I don't understand how one arrives there - in fact, I don't even understand how the function is supposed to be differentiated.

Comment: It is an application of the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^n$$
in the case of matrices.

Comment: @b00nheT so it actually isn't a Taylor Expansion?

Comment: Well: The geometric series represented actually is (equivalent to) the Taylor expansion of the same function. Thus you can indeed think of it as the Taylor expansion

Comment: @b00nheT So would it be possible to directly apply the Taylor expansion, instead of using the (more general) geometric series, that is a result of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: I think so, yet I would not recommend it as Taylor expansions tend to be rather messy, while in this case a direct application of a well known result does the job.

Comment: @b00nheT that does seem reasonable, however as this was an exercise in which the Taylor expansion was explicitly requested, I'd still be curious how this works here